# Sidemenu toggle when div hits top

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I've got a side-menu which toggles open when a certain div hits the top of the window.

The menu also has a toggle button to open and close it.

I'm having a problem where the the script continues to close the menu on scroll after it's been opened manually via the toggle button.

Is there any way of opening and closing the menu only once the div has passed the top of the screen, rather than the script constantly checking?

My script:

```
  var stickyTop = $('#section1').offset().top;

$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
            $('.be-toggled').removeClass('toggled');
        } else {
            $('.be-toggled').addClass('toggled');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your function to a variable, then you can call $(window).off() to remove the window listening to the scroll event.  My example isn't exactly what you need but it should give you the on/off concept when using a function.

```
var stickyTop = $('#section1').offset().top;

var doToggle = function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
      $('.be-toggled').removeClass('toggled');
  } else {
      $('.be-toggled').addClass('toggled');
  }
  $(window).off( 'scroll', doToggle);
});

$(window).on( 'scroll', doToggle);
```

Comment: thanks, very useful! How would I go about using the click on the toggle button as the variable? Thanks